Is there a relative projective tensor (cross-)norm for Banach $A$-algebras?
$\newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}$I am interested in a relative version of the projective tensor product and projective tensor (cross-)norm for Banach algebras. Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be commutative (associative, unital) Banach algebras over $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$ and let $\varphi \colon A \to B$ and $\psi \colon A \to C$ be two bounded homomorphisms. This turns $B$ and $C$ into Banach $A$-algebras. Then we can consider the algebraic pushout given by $B \otimes_A C$, which is an $A$-algebra. For simplicity one can also arrange that:

$\norm{1_A}_A = \norm{1_B}_B = \norm{1_C}_C = 1$ and
$\forall a \in A \ \forall b \in B \ \forall c \in C \colon \norm{a \cdot b}_B \leq \norm a_A \norm b_B, \, \norm{a\cdot c}_C \leq \norm a_A \norm c_C$.

Then the usual projective tensor cross-norm doesn't quite work
$$
\norm a_\otimes = \norm{a \cdot (1_B \otimes 1_C)}_\otimes = \norm{a \otimes 1_C}_\otimes = 
\norm{1_B \otimes a}_\otimes = \norm a_B \norm{1_C}_C = \norm a_B = \norm{1_B}_B \norm a_C = \norm a_C,
$$
since there is a priori no reason why $\norm a_B = \norm a_C$ should hold. We only have $\norm a_B \leq \norm a_A$ and $\norm a_C \leq \norm a_A$. I feel like there is a missing $\sup\limits_{\norm a_A \leq 1}$ or $\inf\limits_{\norm a_A \leq 1}$ modification at the right place of the usual definition, but maybe my intuition is wrong.

Is there a "correct" definition for a relative projective tensor (cross-)norm $\norm\cdot_{\otimes_A}$ (possibly preserving the multiplicativity on pure tensors)? $\norm\cdot_{\otimes_A}$ should recover the usual definition in the case $A = \mathbb{K}$.

I would also appreciate a reference for the construction if there's any.

What's wrong with just taking the quotient of the usual p.t.p. $B\widehat\otimes C$ by the closed ideal generated by all elementary tensors of the form $x\varphi(a)\otimes y -x\otimes \psi(a)y$? (This is the same as the balanced tensor product of $B$ and $C$ regarded as Banach $A$-modules.)

@YemonChoi: I don't see anything wrong with that, I just didn't think of it :-) Do you happen to have a reference for the balanced tensor product of Banach modules? I am asking because I did a somewhat extensive search in the literature before asking and I couldn't find the "relative" tensor product for Banach modules formally stated anywhere.

This is a sort of cheating way of defining a “relative projective tensor norm”, but it is, in my opinion, a quite natural generalization of the usual projective tensor norm:
$$\|\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \otimes c_i\|_\otimes = \sup_{\pi_B: B \to D, \pi_C: C \to D} \|\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_B(b_i)\pi_C(c_i)\|_D$$
where $\pi_B: B \to D$, $\pi_C: C \to D$ range over all contractive unital algebra homomorphisms into commutative unital Banach algebras $D$ s.t. $\pi_B \circ \varphi = \pi_C \circ \psi$.

Thanks! This is a cool construction. In a sense you are constructing the norm following the universal property of the fibered coproduct.

@M.G. Yes, if we consider the category of commutative unital Banach algebras with contractive unital algebra homomorphisms, this norm will exactly define the pushout.

Do you happen to have a reference for more constructions and POVs like this (I mean categorically flavoured for $\mathrm{Ban}$ or $\mathrm{Ban}_1$)? I couldn't find the relative tensor product construction for Banach modules formally stated anywhere. And I did look in Helemskii's books, Ryan's book on tensor products, as well as the very recent  "Homological Methods in Banach Space Theory" by Sánchez, Castillo, and a few more including the older books by Michor and Cigler and Michor.

@M.G. Sorry, I don’t know of any such reference. I come from an operator algebras background, where this kind of construction is quite common in $C^\ast$-algebra theory, e.g., full group $C^\ast$-algebras, full crossed products, maximal tensor norms, universal $C^\ast$-algebras generated by relations, etc., so I kind of just adapted that perspective to here.
